# Change region for existing account in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, region

Trying to move from one region to another in Snowflake as they've released relevant functionality in azure since I set up my account. I cannot find any option to do so, but feels like it should be an easy thing to do!

If it's not possible, how to migrate data easily (it's not a large db - less than 5gb)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot move your account like that, instead you need to set up a new account in the required region  and migrate your data across using replication. Thus process is described here: [Replication](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Replication-How-to-migrate-an-account-from-One-Cloud-Platform-or-Region-to-another-in-Snowflake)

Just out of interest, what platform are you currently on and what functionality is available on Azure that us not available where you currently are?

Comment: I was afraid that might be the case - I created my account when only AWS was supported, and wanted to switch to a closer data centre to where I'm calling the data from - Singapore. Maybe I've been spoilt by switching regions in cloud hosts.